# plotly small numbers showing as `n`, `p` or `f`

Tags: plotly, plotly.js, plotly-python

I am using plotly to plot some data (small numbers) and I see weird formats such as `78.98p`, `576.65n`, `678.76f`

What the F are these? :( There is no explanation anywhere as to what these are.

How can I turn them to say scientific notation with an E?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this https://plot.ly/python/reference/#parcoords-line-colorbar-exponentformat

```
exponentformat ( enumerated : "none" | "e" | "E" | "power" | "SI" | "B" ) 
default: "B" 
Determines a formatting rule for the tick exponents. For example, consider the number 1,000,000,000. If "none", it appears as 1,000,000,000. If "e", 1e+9. If "E", 1E+9. If "power", 1x10^9 (with 9 in a super script). If "SI", 1G. If "B", 1B.
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide a code example, but in general

```py
fig.update_yaxes(exponentformat = 'E')
```

should be what you look for (for values on the y axes).