# How to use this kind of scientific notation tick in plotly?

Tags: python, graph, plotly, scientific-notation

I am using plotly with python and I am trying to use use these kinds of tick in X and Y axis:
10-3, 10-4, 10-5, and so on..

[image]

Any suggestions or recoomended reading?

I am obtaining this:

[image]

Comment: No, the notation in the axis... I am obtaining something like this 1e-3, 1e-2. I want the exponent notation

Answer (score 3):

I was also in a search for this feature, and found the solution in this other answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56742105/418875

You should set `exponentformat` to the `power` option. This will print the ticks as shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe the closes you'll get is [logartihmic axes](https://plotly.com/python/log-plot/):

[image]

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.gapminder().query("year == 2007")

fig = px.scatter(df, x="gdpPercap", y="lifeExp", hover_name="country", log_x=True)
fig.show()
```

Comment: I am already using it! The doubt is related to the representation in logarithmic axis

Answer (score 0):

This has been bugging me for a while, here's the best solution I've found:

TLDR, you can use HTML formatting to make sure the exponent is a superscript and use `array` mode to pass strings for the tick labels to plotly.

```
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np
df = px.data.gapminder().query("year == 2007")

fig = px.scatter(df, x="gdpPercap", y="lifeExp", hover_name="country", log_x=True)
tickvals = np.logspace(3,6, num=4)
print(tickvals)

def format_tick(n: float):
    m, e = f"{n:.0e}".split("e")
    e = int(e)
    return f"{m} x 10<sup>{e}</sup>"

ticktext = [format_tick(t) for t in tickvals]
print(ticktext)

fig.update_layout(
    xaxis = dict(
        tickmode = 'array',
        tickvals = tickvals,
        ticktext = ticktext,
    )
)
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide your code example, but in general

```py
fig.update_xaxes(exponentformat = 'power')
fig.update_yaxes(exponentformat = 'power')
```

should be what you look for.